# Water flow from overhead tank

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, friction, potential-energy

When water is flowing from an over head water tank as shown in the associated picture, Would water lose all it's kinetic energy due to friction in pipe and thus stop flowing ,if the pipe is sufficiently long enough or would water flow always irrespective of length of the pipe?(Assume water tank contain more  water than enough to fill the whole pipe)  Thanks[image]

Comment: There would always be enough initial potential energy to permit some flow, no matter how long the pipe.  It would just get less and less as you increased the pipe length (assuming you are replenishing the fluid in the tank continuously).

Comment: Another way to think about it is that viscous force in a fluid becomes zero when there is no flow. So there will always be a flow when a driving force is present (in your case it is the static head provided by the overhead tank).